# Rounding issue using toFixed()

Tags: reactjs, tofixed

How to `round` 11.255 to 11.26 also 1.005 to 1.01? When I used `toFixed(2)` it returns 11.25 only.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(Math.round(11.255 * 100) / 100)
```

Use `Math.round()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
function convert(val) {
  var n = val.toFixed(2);
  console.log(n);
}
convert(11.255);
```

If the value is a text type, use parseFloat() to convert

```js
function convert(val) {
  var n = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
  console.log(n);
}
convert("11.255");
```